# Access Azure Blob Storage externally from an Asp.Net website

Tags: asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I need to add Azure Blob Storage functionality in an existing classic ASP .NET website in IIS.

### **Website :**

.NET Framework with Forms authentication, Roles enabled.
Hosting Environment : Non Azure Data Centre

### **Roles**

Role 1 : **HeadOffice** ( Users in the company head office )

Role 2 : **CreditCustomer** ( all credit customers are assigned this role )

### **Folders**

1. **HO** - access given to Role 1. Multiple web forms accessed by Role 1.
2. **Customer** - access given to Role 2. Multiple web forms accessed by Role 2.

### **Functionality needed**

### **Access Azure Blob Storage externally :**

**1. HO -** can read write.

**2. Customer -** can read/download.

Need functionality where Customer 1 cannot access blobs for Customer 2 and vice versa.

*Additional Role can be assigned to every customer.*

This is an 2012 article which I think can be modified for my use.

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/803/blob-storage-aspnet-windows-azure

Shall I work with the above or is there an update?
Or
Shall I explore REST API ?

Whatever I do, I intend to host it in the Data Centre (not in Azure) where the website is currently hosted.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: .net framework version?

Comment: .NET Framework 4

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am trying to use microsoft.graph to log the user in via AD before requesting the blob - will let you know if it works

Comment: do you have cors configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` nuget for .NET Framework. The package has been deprecated though and split into smaller package like `Azure.Storage.Queue`,`Azure.Storage.Blobs` etc. So you can use the newer packages by creating a .NET Standard separate library and referring the library in your project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.storage.blob/

Other than nuget, you can use REST API also.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob

**For permission:**
You can create SAS (shared access signature) for different set of permissions and use different SAS based connection string based on role.

Comment: he wants role bases access, NOT sas access - I think SAS access is relatively clear how to do it